# Lightroom CC. Save photo keywords to the actual file

Tags: tagging, lightroom-6

I am really new to lightroom so i´m sorry if i´m missing something very obvious...

I cannot find the way to save the keywords i have assigned to a set of photos in LR to reflect in the actual file. When i see any of the files in Windows Explorer the tags attribute is blank, yet in lightroom i can see the tags perfectly. If i go trough each photo and in the metadata section i click the button next to metadata status then it applies it, but doing this for each file is largely impractical, and pressing the button for a selection of files does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a similar question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6128/how-can-i-get-lightroom-to-sync-datetaken-meta-data-with-other-programs), depending on what you want to do besides looking at the metadata it might be not really constructive to your workflow as mentioned in that answer.

[Adobe Help](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/metadata-basics-actions.html) shows you how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

when you use File/Export..., and scroll through the settings, there is a block about 'Metadata'. Set it to 'Include All Metadata'.

If you use a predefined Export filter, you might have to modify that filter to that setting - use File/Export..., chose that filter on the left, modify the setting, right click the filter name and chose 'Update with current Settings'.